# 'Randomized' probability kernel

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

- Suppose $K: [0,1] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+ := [0,\infty)$
  and $M : [0,1] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ are two 
  probability kernels defined on an underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.
- So, for instance, $K_x : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ is a random variable for each $x \in [0,1]$.
- Suppose that $K$ and $M$ are independent of one another, in the sense that 
  the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{K} := \sigma(K_x : x \in (0,1))$ is independent of the 
  sigma algebra $\mathcal{M} := \sigma(M_x : x \in (0,1))$.
- Suppose $X : \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a random variable independent of both $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{M}$.
- Suppose $f,g : \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ are measurable functions.
- Write $L$ for the law of $X$, which is a probability measure on $[0,1]$.

My question is, is the following equation true (does it make proper sense?), and how does one prove it?

$$
\mathbb{E} (f(K(X)) \cdot g(M(X))
=
\int_{[0,1]}
\mathbb{E}(f(K(x)) \mathbb{E} (g(M(x)) L(dx)
=
\mathbb{E}(f(K(X)) \mathbb{E} (g(M(X)).
$$

Comment: How do you define $M(X)$ ?

Comment: You define X on a different probability space to M say S. Then you take the product of the two probability spaces, $\Omega$ x S,  and then M (X)(w,s) is defined to be M (X (s),w).

Comment: But it shouldn't matter how because after that process you end up with a probability space where M (X) is defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. Intuitively you can see it from the following reasoning. You have assumed independence of $K(X, \omega)$ and $M(X, \omega)$ *conditional* on $x$. But what you are looking for is so to speak *unconditional* independence of these two random variables.

In view of this thought a counterexample can be promptly provided. Simply consider $$K(x, \omega) = M(x, \omega) = x.$$ These random variables are independent, since they are deterministic.The sigma-fields $\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{M}$ they generate are trivial (i.e.: $\mathcal{K} = \mathcal{M} = \{ \emptyset, \Omega\} $) and thus independent of $\sigma(X)$ for any $X$.

Now simply take $f = g = Id$ equal to the identity function.

Then your equality would imply that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X]^2
$$
which does not hold in general (nearly every random variable is a counterexample to this).

As a last remark: the first half of your formula is true.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Are you sure I assumed conditional dependence? I thought my definitions of $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ contained all information whatever the value of $x$ may be?

Comment: You did not assume "conditional dependence" but conditional independence. In the example I give the sigma fields K and M are trivial (because the generating fields are trivial independently of $x$). These fields do not contain information about the r.v. $X$.

Comment: Sorry, yes. So what hypotheses do I need to make the claim true?

Comment: What you need is that the random variables $K(X(\omega), \omega)$ and $M(X(\omega),\omega)$  are independent. This seems rather unlikely to happen. But maybe if you have something particular in mind it's not impossible.